# url encode equivalent in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there an equivalent to PHP's urlencode in Ruby on Rails 2.3.5? (It encodes a string to be used in a query part of a URL)
I googled it but all the answers seem to date back to before 2006 and seems dates.
[This is what I found](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/CGI.html#M000532). It seems a bit abnormal to call `CGI::escape` in a view.

Is there an equivalent helper function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I believe the `u` helper method is what you're looking for:

```
<%=u "URL ENCODE <p>ME</p>" %>
```

This uses the `method ERB::Util.url_encode,` which is aliased to `u`.

You can find the documentation for this method here: http://rdoc.info/stdlib/erb/1.8.7/ERB/Util:url_encode.

Comment: Nope. PHP's urlencode (see http://php.net/urlencode) does things like " " -> "%20".

Comment: Ahh! Haven't had the chance to use that helper yet! SO won't let me switch votes because it doesn't seem to think your answer is edited; I'll check back in a few minutes to see if that changes.

Comment: Link to documentation of the 'u' method would be much appreciated. It seems it's the abbreviation of `url_encode`.

Comment: The [url_encode](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/erb/1.8.7/ERB/Util:url_encode) is a Ruby Core method from ERB::Util module. `u` is an alias for `url_encode`.

Comment: @FilipK Why doesn't `url_encode` come up in the Rails API documentation when you search for it? http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 67):

If you want to do it without ERB, you can use the following:

```
Rack::Utils.escape('http://example.com')
#=> "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com"
```

Which will also convert `/`

Comment: Obviously, don't use this in a view, but this answer helped with the google search that brought me here :)

Answer (score 41):

This worked better for me than the `Rack::Utils.escape`:

```
URI::escape('http://example.com/?param=Hello World')
```

Because it replaced the spaces with `%20` instead of `+`

But it won't replace `/`

Comment: URI::escape seems to have a different use. For instance, it doesn't replace , and : with %2C and %3A nor / with %2F. Rack::Utils does.

Comment: @Abdo I believe URI::escape is for use when inserting a URI into an HTML attribute. I.E. It escapes entities that would cause problems when used like this `href="<%= ... %>"`, such as `"`, `<`, and `>`. Rack::Utils.escape is for when the content will be inserted _within_ a URI, e.g. as a parameter.

Comment: Why is `%20` better than `+`?  Any URL parser will understand both.

Comment: Email clients don't understand +. I'm struggling with this issue at the moment, it's surprisingly difficult to find a decent answer

Comment: this is misleading, URI escape is a different method.   This doesn't convert special characters to url encoded strings..  e.g  "/" to "%2F"

Comment: URI::escape is obsolete and should not be used. Instead, use CGI.escape, URI.encode_www_form or URI.encode_www_form_component depending on your specific use case.

Answer (score 11):

`ERB::Util.html_escape`, which is aliased to `h` and `ERB::Util.url_encode`, which is aliased to `u` .

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB/Util.html

The method names seem to have changed since Sam Soffes answer, but the aliases haven't.