# Ruby on Rails redirect_to not functioning in IF statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, if-statement

I am redirecting a POST request to ensure the URL is correct along with other things. The redirect worked fine before I added in the if statements for town below:

```
if !params[:address].blank?
  town = Town.find(:all, :conditions => ["name = ?", params[:address]])
  @towns = town
  if !town.blank?
    redirect_to '/town/' + params[:address]
  else
    @town_invalid = 'test'
  end
end
```

end

I am sure it is something simple and that I simply cannot see it. Also if you see any glaring errors or code mishaps let me know as I am just starting out.

EDIT: I should mention this is what I get back from Safari when a real town is entered:

```
Safari can’t open the page.Safari can’t open the page “http://localhost:3000/” because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What, if any, errors are you receiving?

Comment: Sorry I just updated, no errors simply that can't open page message.

Comment: params[:address] is the post value, so in the case of a town name being found it will be a string containing 'Barnard Castle'.

Comment: Does anything change if you remove the space from the address?

Comment: I think you may have got it! I just tried a hyphenated town name and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to url encode the `params[:address]`.

```
redirect_to '/town/' + u(params[:address])
```

[url encode equivalent in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353742/url-encode-equivalent-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to evaluate whether it is true or not. Ideally, it should be.

```
   if !params[:address].blank? == true
    town = Town.find(:all, :conditions => ["name = ?", params[:address]])
     @towns = town
     if !town.blank? == true
     redirect_to '/town/' + params[:address]
       else
      @town_invalid = 'test'
    end
   end
```

So here you are saying that if the params( adress ) is not available, it should do otherwise.