# How do you format a url for Google Charts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, google-visualization

I'm trying to convert a url string into a label for a [Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html).

My question is this: my input is something like `www.mysite.com/link` and it needs to be encoded so it can itself be embedded into the Google charts URL.

Before: `www.mysite.com/link/test`

After: `www.mysite.com%2Flink%2Ftest`

How can I convert a regular string into a UTF-8 URL-encoded string in Rails?

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.8 or 1.9? Ruby 1.9 has an `Encoding` class that can help you convert between ASCII and UTF-8 if required, but this is only applicable to non 7-bit ASCII characters.

Comment: @tadman - Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: @tadman - Do valid URLs fall under 7-bit ASCII characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also [`CGI.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000093) from the standard library:

```
>> CGI.escape('www.mysite.com/link/test')
=> "www.mysite.com%2Flink%2Ftest"
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.0 is based on [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/), Rack provides a [Rack::Utils.escape](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Utils.src/M000082.html) method.

```
s = "www.mysite.com/link/test"
# => "www.mysite.com/link/test
Rack::Utils.escape(s)
# => "www.mysite.com%2Flink%2Ftest"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#saved in ./lib/string.rb
class String
  def encode_this
      self.gsub(' ', '%20').gsub('/', '%2F') #etc...
  end
end
```

This would be universal and customizable for your needs.

```
"www.mysite.com/link/test".encode_this
=> "www.mysite.com%2Flink%2Ftest"
```

Comment: If actual URL Encoding is required, I would be careful about rolling your own manually, when other comprehensive solutions probably exist. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353742/url-encode-equivalent-in-ruby-on-rails or `CGI::Escape`