# Sending HTML format to outlook using window.location ="mailto

Tags: javascript, html, outlook-2010

I am trying to send HTML data to outlook, but it comes with plain text.

```
window.location ="mailto:"+emails+" bcc=client@xlgateway.com&subject="+subject+"&body="+body;
```

`body` is HTML table.

Any ideas?

Comment: HTMLEncode the body text in your script.e.g. `Server.HTMLEncode(body)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MailTo with HTML body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to send HTML code as body using mailto.