# MailTo: Add Html Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, smtp, mailto

Is it possible to add html tag like  in mailto body part?

If not, Give some other workaround to achieve this?

I need any other protocol to open the mail client and fill the html formatted text in the html tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MailTo with HTML body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

Comment: @@triplee: not a duplicate. I need any other protocol to open the mail client and fill the html formatted text in the html tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it is a duplicate of [MailTo with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body).

In short, it is not possible, you can only add plain text content.

Comment: @@Carvelis: Is any other way to open the default mail client with html content text in client side?

Comment: No, you can't open mail clients from a web page with anything else than a mailto link, and the official specification states that only plain text is accepted through this link.