# setting a link in the body copy of html mailto

Tags: html, email

I am trying to set a link in the body copy of html mailto and i cant seem to get the link to work... here is my code [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/5pZr7/

for some reason the link doesnt show up and not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
<li id="grey-contactus-icon"><a href= "mailto:info@3cheers.com?subject=info&body=The application beta launch will occur the week of May 28, 2013.  You will be able to sign up then. If you would like us to contact you when the site is live, please click  "href='http://experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers'>here</a></li>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _link doesnt show up_ ?

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/5pZr7/3/

Comment: i think he wants a link inside the body of the email

Comment: Hi pXL... thanks for responding. What I mean is the link that is in the body copy of the mailto email is not showing up showing up in the email  ... please see the example here: here is the email body copy -  "The  application beta launch will occur the week of May 28, 2013.  You will be able to sign up then. If you would like us to contact you when the site is live, please click   .... after click should be "here" which is the link to be clicked on.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Refer this: [MailTo with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

It is not possible to have `html` in the body of the email if you to generate it using `mailto`

Well, you can just write the url as the part of the email. Most of the modern mail-clients will automatically recognise it.

```
<li id="grey-contactus-icon"><a href= "mailto:info@3cheers.com?subject=info&body=The application beta launch will occur the week of May 28, 2013.  You will be able to sign up then. If you would like us to contact you when the site is live, please click  http://experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers here">Click to send email</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks draxxxeus for your response. Tried this but to no avail,  Appreciate you help

Comment: Do you see the expected link in the mail body?

Answer (score 0):

You have another href starting within the href text.
remove the following:

```
href='http://experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers'
```

Here it is fixed:

```
<li id="grey-contactus-icon"><a href= "mailto:info@3cheers.com?subject=info&body=The application beta launch will occur the week of May 28, 2013.  You will be able to sign up then. If you would like us to contact you when the site is live, please click ">here</a></li>
```

jsFiddle Fixed:
http://jsfiddle.net/5pZr7/1/

**EDIT - FIXED --- TWO OPTIONS, LOOK AT CODE BELLOW**

Two options:

1) with an email and an html link inside it:

```
<li id="grey-contactus-icon"><a href= "mailto:info@3cheers.com?subject=info&body=The 3Cheers     application beta launch will occur the week of May 28, 2013.  You will be able to sign up then. If you would like us to contact you when the site is live, please click &lt;a href=&quot;http://experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers&quot;&gt;this link&lt;/a&gt;">

   Html Link</a></li>
```

2) with an email with no html link inside it (should work in most email clients this way!)

```
 <li id="grey-contactus-icon"><a href= "mailto:info@3cheers.com?subject=info&body=The 3Cheers application beta launch will occur the week of May 28, 2013.  You will be able to sign up then. If you would like us to contact you when the site is live, please click &lt;a href=&quot;http://experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers&quot;&gt;this link&lt;/a&gt;">

   Pure Link</a></li>
```

updated fiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/5pZr7/8/

**EDIT 2 - mailto url encoded link**

```
<li id="grey-contactus-icon"><a href= "mailto:info@3cheers.com?subject=info&body=The 3Cheers application beta launch will occur the week of May 28, 2013.  You will be able to sign up then. If you would like us to contact you when the site is live, please click %3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fexperience.maritzmotivation.com%2FMoreInfo3Cheers%22%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fexperience.maritzmotivation.com%2FMoreInfo3Cheers%3C%2Fa%3E">try this </a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Dory but the other url is needed. so I have a mail button on the page and when user clicks the button it opens up the mail client( mailto) and within the body copy is a link that the user can click on to get further info. hope that makes sense.

Comment: yes, but then you need to prob url encode the link into the message, otherwise it doesn't know what to do..I'll try to revise my answer for you .

Comment: Thanks Dory! only thing is i need the link to be clickable and open up to the link url... is that possible? thanks again and appreciate your patience!

Comment: it is clickable, try one of the two options. option 2 worked for me with Outlook fine..

Comment: not sure why it isnt working on my end... issue with apple maili guess which is my default email client that comes up

Comment: both the types of links aren't working? What are you getting in your email client? do you see the http coming up in the email subjet?

Comment: yeah both aren't working. Here's what I have in the body of my email...        "The 3Cheers application beta launch will occur the week of May 28, 2013.  You will be able to sign up then. If you would like us to contact you when the site is live, please click <a href="http://experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers">this link</a> . but "this link is not clickable to open to the url(http://experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers")

Comment: Hi Dory tried the second option and still "this link" is not clickable and doesn't open the url(experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers"). not sure why. really appreciate your help and your time.

Comment: tried edit 2 and it didn't. the user has to be able to click on "this link" in the email body text and be taken to the url(experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers")

Comment: can you try use another email client for a test? what did you get in your email in your email client?

Comment: unfortunately apple mail is the only mail client currently set up on this mac. I am getting in the email is: body copy: The application beta launch will occur the week of May 28, 2013.  You will be able to sign up then. If you would like us to contact you when the site is live, please click <a href="http://experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers">here</a> .... "here" for some reason is not a click able link. you should be able to click on "here" and it brings you to "http://experience.maritzmotivation.com/MoreInfo3Cheers". but its just not working