# How do I pre-populate an email link with an html formatted email

Tags: html, email

If I wanted to prepopulate an email link like: (in a really simple format, pardon for the bad example.)

```
<a href="mailto:barney@example.com?subject=About your bouncy ball&body=<img src='example.com/images/logo.png'>Hey Barney, Is your bouncy ball still for sale?">Email 3 Barney Today!</a>
```

and have the html actually show as html, is there a way to do so.

Comment: No. You need a pre-processor from what I think you're asking. Although your entire question is very unclear so who knows.

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is not part of the design of the `mailto` anchor href, according to [RFC 2368](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt):

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is the
>      body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the content for
>      the first text/plain body part of the message. The mailto URL is
>      primarily intended for generation of short text messages that are
>      actually the content of automatic processing (such as "subscribe"
>      messages for mailing lists), not general MIME bodies.

To do as you describe, you would be better off looking into a pre-processor like PHP.

Comment: Righto, Ill abuse sendgrid, this makes me sad though.