# Can I reliably set the subject and body of an email in a form using mailto:?

Tags: html, forms, mailto

I'd like to use web form to generate an email using `mailto:`,
with the subject and body specified by the user in the form.
Is this supported?

The subject and body can be specified in a regular hyperlink, like this:

```
mailto:a@b.c?subject=d e&body=f g
```

I'm testing this with Firefox and Outlook and it works fine: Outlook pre-fills the subject and body with `d e` and `f g`, as desired.

Of course, those spaces should really be URL-encoded:

```
mailto:a@b.c?subject=d%20e&body=f%20g
```

This works, too: spaces appear in Outlook.

(How universal is this? Can I assume it will work for 95% of my users who have their `mailto` handler set up correctly?)

Now I want to supply the subject and body in form fields:

```
<form method="method" action="mailto:a@b.c" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="text" name="subject" value="d e">
<input type="text" name="body" value="f g">
</form>
```

This *almost* works: the spaces are replaced with plus signs.
Even when I type new values in the text fields.

How can I get spaces?

*(A related question: [HTML mailto form: prefill subject and body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996602/html-mailto-form-prefill-subject-and-body).)*

PS: I suppose it can be done [using JavaScript to submit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637406/how-do-i-add-html-form-data-to-a-mailto-link).  I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: My guess is that every modern OS/browser has a built in email handler that will,  at the very least, ask the user which email program/site they want to use.  I guess with the form, you may need to url encode the spaces as well.

Comment: But how to encode the spaces that the users type?