# pass parameters from URL to mailto command

Tags: html

I have a URL that contains parameters.  I'm trying to create a mailto command that will open the link of the current window's URL.  I am currently using the following JS to call the function, but it truncates the URL after the "&" sign.

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=Report&body=[sub]" onclick="this.href = this.href.replace(''[sub]'',window.location)">email</a>
```

This returns "http://www.mydomain.com/reportname?SiteCode=0027" in the body of the email, but the URL is actually listed below as it is passing variables:
http://www.mydomain.com/reportname?SiteCode=0027&CustomerCode=ALLCUSTOMERS&JobCode=ALLJOBS

How can I output the entire URL including the parameters to an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AngDe/2/). I made two minor changes.

1. First I *changed the href attribute onClick*, and did set it on **DOMContentLoaded**.
2. Second I had to use encodeURIComponent as any special char will break your script

Credits goes to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body) and [dr. google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mailto%20&%20body%20not%20working&oq=mailto%20&%22&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)!

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var simpleHref = document.getElementById("simpleHref");
            simpleHref.href = "mailto:asdf@asdf.com?subject=Report&body=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="" id="simpleHref">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```