# Pre-populate email with an image

Tags: html, email, href, mailto

I have successfully pre-poulated an email with a subject and body in plain text like so:

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com?subject=test&body=message">Contact Us</a>
```

What I would like to do is have an image at the bottom of the email and was wondering if this was possible seeing as it's an encoded URL string.

I was thinking it might be possible encoding an `<img>` tag but gathered it would just appear as plain text.

If it is possible, could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [MailTo with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

> No. This is not possible at all.

Credit: [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)

Comment: Thanks for the info. A shame it isn't possible as it would be such a handy thing to have

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible

Possibles are: **SUBJECT,CC,BCC,BODY**

```
<a href="mailto:YourName@YourSite.com? cc=someone@YourSite.com&bcc=someoneElse@YourSite.com &subject=Shipping%20Information%20Request&body=Please%20tell%20me%20if%20my%20order%20has%20shipped!">Shipping Request</a>
```