# How to make text in an email bold with URL encoding

Tags: html, email, html-email, urlencode

I am using a mailto link with URL encoding to populate an email, and I want to make some of the text in the email body bold.  I have tried using HTML tags and asterisks already, and googling didn't turn up anything helpful.  Is it possible?

I am writing a chrome extension that needs to work with Outlook specifically.

Here's an example of my encoding:

```
"mailto:xyz@example.com?Subject=Hello&amp;Body=This%20should%20be%20bold!"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MailTo with HTML body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. This is not possible at all.

As you can see in [RFC 2368](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt), this is not possible at all:

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is the
>   body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the content for
>   the first text/plain body part of the message. The mailto URL is
>   primarily intended for generation of short text messages that are
>   actually the content of automatic processing (such as "subscribe"
>   messages for mailing lists), not general MIME bodies.

Credit to the top two answers (Quentin and Alfonso Marin) on the linked duplicate answer.

Comment: The [duplicate question (MailTo with HTML body)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body) was the third link (and first StackOverflow link) on google for the term "html in mailto".

Comment: I see.  Thanks for clearing this up for me.  I didn't google hard enough and suffered from wishful thinking.