# Forward to friend link with HTML not working

Tags: php, html, mailto

I need to add "Forward to friend" link in my email,I was try

```
 <a href="mailto:enteryour@addresshere.com?subject=Website Name&body=Link to website, short description">Send me an email</a>
```

It is working properly,
But i need to send body as HTML content in the body,I try

```
 <a href="mailto:enteryour@addresshere.com?subject=Website Name&body=<span>Test</span>">Send me an email</a>
```

But `body=<span>Test</span`> is not working,How to do this?
Anyone have idea about this?

Comment: Have you tried url encoding it?

Comment: no,How to do?using urlencode()?

Comment: I try with urlencode(),But it will result the entair html as text in mail body

Comment: Probably it's not possible, there is a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use html in a mailto link.

For a guide on how to use the mailto link, see https://yoast.com/guide-mailto-links/