# Customize mailto in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, mailto

Is it possible to add any type of formatting to a mailto link used in Outlook? Basically I have an email to send with an image that includes a mailto hyperlink. I know I can use the following to get it to customize the subject and body

```
mailto:email@address.com?subject=Email subject here&body=Email body here
```

But is it possible to style the body text at all, e.g. make text bold?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body

Comment: That question seems to be regarding mailto in an HTML file, since it references an href, mine is using the hyperlink function in Outlook 2010

Comment: Even though the method is different, the mailto link itself has a fixed format. Remember, this has to work in all email clients when you click it, so Outlook can't do any "fancy" stuff to it that differs from the standard. That link should give you the info you are after.