# How to send table html with email using mailto?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I want to send a email using a href="mailto.."
I have this working code below:

```
<cfset month = URL.Month>
<cfset year = URL.Year>
<cfquery datasource="newsletters" name="testing">
SELECT * FROM departments_names
where dates >='#datestart#' and dates < #dateend#
AND shooting_star_dept_name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
DATEPART(year, dates),
DATEPART(month, dates),
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="testing" GROUP="deptartmetn_name">
<tr>
<td>
<a href="mailto:?subject=#month#/#year#%20%20Results%20for%20newsletters&
body=#total_count#%20#total/total_count#">
Send email to #deptartmetn_name#</a></td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
```

Which just send a simple "12/2" (for example).
I would like to be able to send more than just simple text.
I would like when i click on a link to be able to send a table like below:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr >
<th> First Name</th>
<th> Last Name</th>
<th>total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<cfoutput query="testing">
<tbody>
<tr >
<td>#employee_name#</td>
<td>#employee_lastname#</td>
<td>#total_count#</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

I would like to see what I'm sending first to the recipient. 
Would something like this be possible or is there a better way to do this?
My first post here and beginner to coding.

Comment: No, that is not possible. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body

Comment: @gauravS ok that sames me time from actually trying to make it work. Well i guess my other option is using cfmail.

Comment: You could send yourself the email first or save it into a variable and output it to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AJAX callback on your links and use `cfmail` with `cfsavecontent` (for the actual HTML content/body of the message) in your callback handler code.