# Mailto:subject age old query

Tags: html

I have a question and I think I know the answer.

Have some html code where im using the action="mailto: function.

My question is can I assign the Subject to the generated email from the selection in the code below? E.g. Subject: Urgent; when urgent is selected.

```
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="text/plain" method="post" id="orderform" action="mailto:randomeemail@gmail.com?subject" >
<table border="1" align="left" style="width: 100%">
    <tbody>`enter code here`
      <tr>
       <td style="text-align: justify;"><label for="element_10" class="Deliverys">What
           Type of Delivery is required?</label></td>
        <td style="text-align: justify;">
          <select name="Urgency Required">
            <option value="Standard">Standard Delivery</option>
            <option value="Fast">Fast</option>
            <option value="Urgent">Urgent</option>
            <option value="Required in 4 hours">Required in 4 hours</option>
            <option value="Required in 2 hours">Required in 2 hours</option>
            <option value="Pick-up">Pick-up</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Javascript, you can do the following:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
  window.location.href = 'mailto:randomeemail@gmail.com?subject=' + document.querySelector('select[name="Urgency Required"]').value
  return false
}
</script>

<form enctype="text/plain" method="post" id="orderform" onsubmit="return myFunction();" >
<table border="1" align="left" style="width: 100%">
    <tbody>`enter code here`
      <tr>
       <td style="text-align: justify;"><label for="element_10" class="Deliverys">What
           Type of Delivery is required?</label></td>
        <td style="text-align: justify;">
          <select name="Urgency Required">
            <option value="Standard">Standard Delivery</option>
            <option value="Fast">Fast</option>
            <option value="Urgent">Urgent</option>
            <option value="Required in 4 hours">Required in 4 hours</option>
            <option value="Required in 2 hours">Required in 2 hours</option>
            <option value="Pick-up">Pick-up</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"></input>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Bascially, when the form submits, it'll dynamically generate the mailto link, and open it. It then returns false, which stops the form from actually submitting (i.e. redirecting to the action).

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response, I tried this out however the selection reverts to the body of the email leaving subject line blank.

Comment: Also java is perfect by me

Comment: What internet browser/email client?

Comment: Hi have tried IE Chrome and Firefox. to Lotus notes, Gmail, outlook.

Comment: A pleasure, please let us know what you had to change to make it work! :)

Comment: Now working, Thankyou!!! strike that, the subject pops in, which is awesome, but the body no longer comes up..t2 steps forward 1 step back lol

Comment: Check out the examples here `mailto:email@address.com?subject=Hello world&body=Line one%0DLine two` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body#10520399

Comment: your last code update works for the subject, however in negates the email body, which is a shame. So close

Comment: seen the example, but my form is quite large, is there anything i can do to include the rest of the form input?