# How can I launch an email client on ios using Swfit

Tags: ios, swift

In Android, I can launch an email client from my android application using its Intent mechanism.
In ios, how can I launch its email client from my ios application using Swift?

Thank you.

Comment: Du you want to send an a mail or start an app?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:jon.doe@mail.com")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

Note that this works only on a device, not in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks. Can I added "Subject" and "Body" when launches the email app?

Comment: Yes, you can use the url scheme. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) for instructions. And there is even a [generator](http://www.mailto.co.uk). -- Ah, yes, and don't forget to tick the checkmark above.

Comment: Once the mail app launches, tapping the "cancel" button on the mail app view causes the app to crash, is there a solution for this? I also tried MFComposeViewController but getting the exact same result

Answer (score 6):

**SWIFT 3:** The openEmail function will try to use the iOS Mail app if it is available (user has atleast one email account setup). Otherwise it will use the mailto: url (see full example at the bottom of my reply) to launch a mail client.

```
import MessageUI
// Make your view controller conform to MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
class Foo: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    func openEmail(_ emailAddress: String) {
        // If user has not setup any email account in the iOS Mail app
        if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            print("Mail services are not available")
            let url = URL(string: "mailto:" + emailAddress)
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
            return
        }

        // Use the iOS Mail app
        let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        composeVC.setToRecipients([emailAddress])
        composeVC.setSubject("")
        composeVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)

        // Present the view controller modally.
        self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: MailComposeViewControllerDelegate
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

An all out mailto example with subject, body, and cc:

> "mailto:me@gmail.com?subject=Hey whats up man!&body=This is from a
>   great example I found online.&cc=someoneelse@yahooo.com&bcc=whostillusesthis@hotmail.com"

Answer (score 5):

I found a great solution from [Hacking in Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-send-an-email) by Paul Hudson. In Swift 3, Add `import MessageUI` to the top of the file and make the class conform to `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol.

```
func sendEmail() {
  if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
   let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
   mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
   mail.setToRecipients(["example@example.com"])
   mail.setMessageBody("<p>You're so awesome!</p>", isHTML: true)

   present(mail, animated: true)
   } else {
   // show failure alert
  }
}

// MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Conformance

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update iOS 10+**

//Use for Open mail application or open any link with browser!

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:your_mail_here@mail.com")

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
   // Fallback on earlier versions
   UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated for Xcode 12.5

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:mailto:someone@example.com")
                                                UIApplication.shared.open(url! as URL)
```

or if you would like to add an embedded subject

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com&body=This%20is%20the%20body")
```

or if you want to add multiple email addresses

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:mailto:someone@example.com,someoneelse@example.com")
                                                    UIApplication.shared.open(url! as URL)
```