# Let the user choose an e-mail client on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, email

We would like to give the ability to the user to choose any installed email client (Gmail, Yandex, etc.) in our app. But iOS provides only Mail or builtin `MFMailComposeViewController`. Is there any way to present a list of email clients to the user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I launch an email client on ios using Swfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052815/how-can-i-launch-an-email-client-on-ios-using-swfit)

Comment: iMail?  iMail View Controller?

Comment: I mean Mail or MFMailComposeViewController

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no way to achieve this directly, as iOS doesn't know the concept of 'default application'. You could implement yourself a function which checks the various URLs used by different iOS email clients, and determines which clients are installed. For instance, GMail uses `googlegmail://`. You could also show a menu with the clients found on the device.

If you don't want to create your own implementation, [ThirdPartyMailer](https://github.com/vtourraine/ThirdPartyMailer) is a library that can do this for you.

Comment: In this ThirdPartyMailer how to attach the zip file in the mail compose?

Comment: Since iOS14 users can now set a default email app, which will be used when you use mailto:// in your app

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something similar to the way Android handles it, then no it's not possible. Some email apps though might support a custom scheme - for example Gmail uses `googlegmail://` (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114455/open-gmail-app-from-my-app)).

Answer (score -3):

You should try something like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:jon.doe@mail.com")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

Comment: Thanks but this opens iMail.

Comment: So you have to create your own Picker with list of available mail clients. To build this list you can check for each scheme if `canOpenUrl:` it will tell you if user has installed the application or not

Comment: I am wondering if there is way to present all apps, that can handle "mailto" links.

Comment: I don't think so