# How to send user to mail app with specific email address

Tags: ios, swift

If I use the email address "appname.app@company.co.za" then it doesn't work but if I try appname@company.co.za then it works.

I've tried this from [How to open mail app from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981422/how-to-open-mail-app-from-swift)

```
let url = NSURL(string: "appname.app@company.co.za")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

and this

```
let url = NSURL(string: "appname.app@company.co.za".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

Comment: Have you tried to prepend "mailto:"? `let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:appname.app@company.co.za".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)`

Comment: right. I feel bad now. I removed the mailto part when changing the email address.