# iOS: Adding an IBAction to part of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have and UILabel and I want to add and IBAction in the word "email" to open the email client in the iPhone. Here is my code:

```
func setInfoLabel() {
    self.myLabel.text = "send me and email if you need more information"
}
```

Any of you knows how can I add the action to the word in the UILabel?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create tap-able "links" in the NSAttributedText of a UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedtext-of-a-uilabel)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do this. Either add a button, or a UITextView with a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **UIButton** instead of **UILabel** because it was created for displaying text only, however, if you still want to use it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
    self.myLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
} 

/* will be called when tapping on the label */
@objc func tapAction() -> Void {
    
}
```

Comment: But this it would add the action to all the UILabel. There is no way to just be add it to the word in the UILabel?

Comment: Unless you render font glyphs manually and track sizes and position which is very complicated

Answer (score 0):

You apparently can't make an IBAction only on apart of label. Either use a separate label or UIButton for the word email and put them right next to each other so that it appears like a single element.

Answer (score 0):

You should use attributed text to specify area to be linked in one sentence.

[Maybe you can find the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519273/1877100)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add an IBOutlet to a certain word for a UILabel. You could look at [ActiveLabel](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift), this has the functionality you need.

Here is also a link to how to open mail if you need it :D, [open mail in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981422/how-to-open-mail-app-from-swift).

Hope this helps and good luck.