# Refer a friend through SMS in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, sms, refer

Hi want want to make a refer a friend through SMS I write the following code. If user is pick on that open the SMS with text but it don't cancel again user will unable go back to app.

```
if indexPath.item == 1
        {
            //SMS
            if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {

                let urlToShare = self.referalmodeldata[0].referralCodeOnly

                controller1.body = "Hey I just gave an Awesome Assessment on App you can also try it. I scored , Try to beat my score \(String(describing: urlToShare))"

                controller1.messageComposeDelegate = self as? MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
                self.present(controller1, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't implemented `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` correctly in your code.

First of all you need to confirm `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` with your `UIViewController` as shown below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
```

Next thing is you need add it's delegate method as shown below:

```
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then you need to replace

```
controller1.messageComposeDelegate = self as? MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

with

```
controller1.messageComposeDelegate = self
```

Demo code will be:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func sendText(_ sender: Any) {
        if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
            let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            controller.body = "Message Body"
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes for email you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981422/how-to-open-mail-app-from-swift

Comment: And don't forget to mark answer as correct if that helps you.. :) @SrikanthThirumalasetty