# How do I pass variables into MFMailComposeViewController() using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using the code provided in answer 2 of [SwiftUI: Send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784722/swiftui-send-email) and it works fine as is. However, in my app, I want to set the vc.setSubject to include some variables:

```
vc.setSubject("2020_\(riderFlagNumber)_\(activeBonus.category)_\(activeBonus.city)_\(activeBonus.state),\(activeBonus.code)")
```

riderFlagNumber comes from userDefaults and works fine; but the ones marked as activeBonus are coming from the navigation detail view that triggers the email. They come from an ObservableObject that appears to only be accessible from a view. How do I pass these variables from that view into the MFMailComposeViewController()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the view you specify that contains ObservableObject class looks like below

```
class activeBonus: ObservableObject {
    @Published var category: String = "ABC"
    @Published var city: String = "Seoul"
}
```

If so, in the file that contains MFMailComposeViewController() add the following (@ObserverObject line specified in the below code):

```
struct MailView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?
    @ObservedObject var activeBonus = activeBonus()
```

Once the line with @ObservedObject is added, the subject line you have mentioned will work.