# SwiftUI: Send email without showing the mail app

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am using

```
struct MailView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

        @Binding var isShowing: Bool
        @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?

        init(isShowing: Binding<Bool>, result: Binding<Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?>) {
            _isShowing = isShowing
            _result = result
        }

        func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
            defer {
                isShowing = false
            }
            guard error == nil else {
                self.result = .failure(error!)
                return
            }
            self.result = .success(result)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {return Coordinator(isShowing: $isShowing,result: $result)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MailView>) -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let vc = MFMailComposeViewController()
        vc.setToRecipients(["test@test.de"])
        vc.setSubject("Hello!")
        vc.setMessageBody("Hello this is my message body!", isHTML: false)
        vc.mailComposeDelegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MFMailComposeViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MailView>) {

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>? = nil
    @State var isShowingMailView = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
                Button("Show mail view") {
                    self.isShowingMailView.toggle()
                }
            } else {
                Text("Can't send emails from this device")
            }
            if result != nil {
                Text("Result: \(String(describing: result))")
                    .lineLimit(nil)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingMailView) {
            MailView(isShowing: self.$isShowingMailView, result: self.$result)
        }
    }
}
```

from [SwiftUI: Send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784722/swiftui-send-email/56785754#56785754) and it works but shows every time the mail app in a separate sheet. How can I disable showing the mail app? Just tapping the button "Show mail view" and then the email is sent without showing the mail app.

Comment: not possible if you are using `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to secretly send an email by using `MFMailComposeViewController`. Generally speaking, iOS SDK doesn't allow to send an email without displaying the email controller.
The best solution here is to implement the email service API on the backend and ask iOS application to call the endpoint.