# Error trying to send an email using messageui library

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using the code below found on another stack overflow page I keep getting this error when a button is pressed to form an email within my app I am currently working on. Can someone help?

error: [PPT] Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT.

```
import Foundation
import MessageUI

class EmailHelper: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    public static let shared = EmailHelper()
    private override init() {
        //
    }
    
    func sendEmail(subject:String, body:String, to:String){
        if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            // Utilities.showErrorBanner(title: "No mail account found", subtitle: "Please setup a mail account")
            return //EXIT
        }
        
        let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
        
        picker.setSubject(subject)
        picker.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: true)
        picker.setToRecipients([to])
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
        
        EmailHelper.getRootViewController()?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        EmailHelper.getRootViewController()?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    static func getRootViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController

         // OR If you use SwiftUI 2.0 based WindowGroup try this one
         // UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
    }
}
Button(action: {
   EmailHelper.shared.sendEmail(subject: "Anything...", body: "", to: "")
 }) {
     Text("Send Email")
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784722/swiftui-send-email

Comment: this doesn't help as I encounter the error in my question