# How to send an email in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Specifically, I made a quiz in a navigation view. I want to learn how to send my quiz answers (from textfields) to my email.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784722/swiftui-send-email

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784722/swiftui-send-email)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The package: https://github.com/Kitura/Swift-SMTP

Use:

```swift
import SwiftSMTP

func sendMail(to receiver: Mail.User) {
    let smtp = SMTP(
        hostname: "smtp.gmail.com",     // SMTP server address
        email: "user@gmail.com",        // username to login
        password: "password"            // password to login
    )
    
    let me = Mail.User(
        name: "User",
        email: "user@gmail.com"
    )
    
    let mail = Mail(
        from: me,
        to: [receiver],
        subject: "Humans and robots living together in harmony and equality.",
        text: "That was my ultimate wish."
    )
    
    smtp.send(mail) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("Send email successful")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll try that out.