# Adding a hyperlink to 'Mailto' Body text

Tags: url, encoding, hyperlink

I am currently working on mailchimp to produce an email forwarding button. When you press this button some text appears in an appear which you then send to others. I have used the code below. I want to have a hyperlink for the "www.dailypnut.com" address as currently it appears in the email as just text. How do I do this?

```
<p style="background-color:#3b5998; width:200px; height:40px;
opacity:0.8;margin:auto;margin-top:15px; margin-bottom;px;
text-align:center;line-height:40px"><a href="mailto:?Subject=The Daily 
Pnut:The World in a Nutshell&amp;Body=%20Sign%20up%20for%20the%20
Daily%20Pnut.%20A%20humorous%20daily%20summary%20of%20world%20affairs
%20-%20www.dailypnut.com" style="text-decoration:none"><b style=
"color:white;text-decoration:none; opacity:0.9;text-transform: uppercase;
font-size:14px">Forward the Pnut!</b></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour depends on the e-mail client, so you won't get a solution for this in your html.

Unfortunately you can only specify a plain body in `mailto` (see for example [MailTo with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)). Since a lot of e-mail clients today only allow editing of the html body, and hence 'convert' the plain body into html when it is loaded, they will most likely replace URLs with links during conversion.

The result is that the behaviour of your `mailto` link will be different depending on the user's email client.