# I have a html table I would like to open it on outlook compose message when a button is clicked Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a html table I would like to open it on outlook compose message when a button is clicked Is it possible?

[The design I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIdtL.jpg)

Comment: I think you want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body

Comment: They say like its not possible.Can it be done through some way .