# Clickable link in body of mailto

Tags: wordpress

How to add clickable link in body of mailto?

```
<li><a href="mailto:?subject=Negotiation  Event&body=Check out : https://cc200.infusionsoft.com/"><span class="icon-email"></span></a></li>
```

It simply displaying https://cc200.infusionsoft.com/ in body of mail rather than clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be impossible.
here's example of multiple emails with subject and body.

```html
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?cc=someoneelse@theirsite.com, another@thatsite.com, me@mysite.com&bcc=lastperson@theirsite.com&subject=Big%20News&body=Body-goes-here">Email Us</a>
```

check this question-
[MailTo with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)