# Angulajrs : set html file content to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to send an email with Angularjs.

```
$window.open("mailto:"+ emailId + "?subject=" + subject+"&body="+message,"_self");
```

The body is stored in a HTML file, its content :

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>This is a test mail template</p></div>
<p>I hope you can help me on this</p>
<p>Thank you </p>
<p>Good bye</p>
```

How can I load the html content of this file into the message variable?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the file stored?

Comment: AFAIK - [You can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

Comment: You should be able to load it making a GET request using the `$http` service. Then after the promise resolves you open the window with the mailto: protocol.