# Mailto <Form> create breaks in the actual email

Tags: html, forms, mailto

This is my code:

```
<form action="mailto:helpdesk@work.com?subject=Websense Block Page" method="post" enctype="text/plain>

User Name: $*WS_USERNAME*$<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value ="$*WS_USERNAME*$"><br>
<STRONG>Workstation:</STRONG><br>
<input type="text" name="WORKSTATION"value ="$*WS_WORKSTATION*$"><br>
<STRONG>Current Date:</STRONG><br>
<input type="text" name="DATE" value ="$*WS_DATE*$"><br>
<STRONG>Category:</STRONG><br>
<input type="text" name="CATAGORY" value ="$*WS_CATEGORY*$"><br>    
<STRONG>Requested URL:</STRONG><br>
<input type="text" name="RequestedURL" value ="$*WS_URL*$"><br> 
<STRONG>Comment:</STRONG><br>
<input type="text" name="COMMENT" size="50"><br><br>
<STRONG>Status</STRONG>: Is this an Emergency?
<input type="radio" name="emergency" value="YES">Yes
<input type="radio" name="emergency" value="no">No
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

The output of this puts all of the information in a single line in the body of the email. Is there a way to put each field in a new row in the email?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MailTo with HTML body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

Comment: Thanks, I did read this before I posted my question :) I know that it is possible to format the email, but I haven't seen one address the <form> code. Similar, I know, but I think there has to be an answer out there. My googling is coming up short.

Comment: The form submission just carries data, not formatting. You **must** format the email data if you want formatting. You can't do anything to the form itself to change the email formatting.

Comment: Thank You Scott! That is what I needed to know!

Comment: Can you @scott point me in the best direction to accomplish this?

Comment: No. That all depends upon what you are using to send the email - php, asp, cgi, perl... etc.