# HTML prefill mail options with input from HTML form

Tags: html, forms

[image: How it looks online]

```
<form action="mailto:mail@mail.com" method="post" class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Naam" name="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Onderwerp" name="subject">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Bericht" rows="7" name"message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                        <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="SHOOT MESSAGE">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

The above code gives the underneath result when I 'shoot the message'.

[image: how it looks]

It should fill in the message with the message from the form, same goes for the subject.

Now the question is: can this be done with HTML 5 only? I know that I can send it with PHP but that is not my question.

Comment: Yes, if you're using JS.

Comment: Is it possible without JS? Like a new HTML5 attribute?

Comment: You can't set the message. You can only set the to, CC, and subject fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use JavaScript, the following might come in handy:
[image]

Source: [MailTo with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)