# Having an HTML body when using the Gmail URL scheme in Swift 3

Tags: swift, gmail

I'm looking to call the Gmail app with a preconfigured subject and the body contains HTML using the following:

```
let gmail = URL(string:"googlegmail:///co?subject=Subject&body=<body><H1>testing</H1></body>")
UIApplication.shared.openURL(gmail!)
```

This will crash the app, I then resort to:

```
var messageEncoded1 = "<body><H1>testing</H1></body>".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)
let gmail = URL(string:"googlegmail:///co?subject=Subject&body="+messageEncoded1!")
UIApplication.shared.openURL(gmail!)
```

And this will create a URL and open Gmail, however, body of the email shows: `<body><H1>testing</H1></body>` and not the work `testing` like so:

## testing

So the question is, is there a way to specify that the body holds HTML so that Gmail can render it as HTML?

Comment: Try and see if you can use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for the start and end tags.

Comment: Can you provide an example perhaps? Not to sure what these mean

Comment: Posted it as an answer. Hope it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mailto link with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @user481610 Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: solution found ?

Answer (score 1):

No, for now, Gmail doesn't render it as HTML. Moreover, `mailto` standard [RFC2368](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) itself doesn't obligate to render tags in `body` property:

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is the
> body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the content for
> the first text/plain body part of the message. The mailto URL is
> primarily intended for generation of short text messages that are
> actually the content of automatic processing (such as "subscribe"
> messages for mailing lists), not general MIME bodies.