# How to add css/style tags to body in mailto function in javascript or vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, mailto

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=look at this website&body=<b>Hi,I found</b> this website
and thought you might like it http://www.google.com/">tell a friend</a>
```

after click output should be in outlook window :

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=look at this website&body=**Hi,I found** this website
and thought you might like it http://www.google.com/">tell a friend</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MailTo with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)