# Jquery Alternative to mailto link with html body

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this variable like so:

```
var htmlBody = "<table border = '1' cellspacing='0' align = 'center'><tr><th>Job #</th><th>Task</th><th>Date</th></tr></table>”;
```

What I tried to do is create a mailto link so the email client opens with To empty, the subject Schedule and the body as htmlBody

```
window.location = "mailto:?subject=Schedule&body=" + htmlBody;
```

However you cannot have html code in a mailto link, so is there an alternative to what I am trying accomplish? I don't want to send the email, I just want the client to open with Subject and htmlBody.

Or is there away to accomplish what I am trying to do with ASP.NET MVC? I open to either jquery or .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open an email programmatically you can use window.location.assign with a mailto: link:

```
window.location.assign('mailto:test@test.com');
```

Pass your parameters as query string like you did:

```
window.location.assign('mailto:test@test.com?subject=test&body=testBody');
```

Passing HTML to the body is not possible as seen here: [MailTo with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

Comment: Yes, but you cannot use html in the body with mailto