# How to pass html tags with text to EMAIL BODY in mail popup opened with MAILTO

Tags: javascript, php, html, mailto

I want set the body of mailto popup with coloured/bold texts

I have gone through many links but not able to get the solution.

following is the code I am actually using... I am trying to set this

```
<b>MANSI</b>
```

to the bodyText in following line

```
 window.location.href = 'mailto:' + encodeURIComponent(responseData.myEmail) + '?Subject=' + encodeURIComponent(responseData.subject) + '&Body=' + encodeURIComponent(bodyText ? bodyText : ' ')
```

**Is it really possible to do that?**

I have also trid with this simple line

```
 <a href="mailto:?subject=look at this website&body=<strong>Hi,I found this </strong><b>website</b>........">Demo</a>
```

Please help me to achive this I have already wasted so much time to googling it..

Your help will be appreciated.

My ultimate goal is...

> I want to open an outlook new mail popup on click of a button from a page on magento admin panel. It could have pre-fromatted text like specific color and font decoration like bold and would want outlook to consider html and populate necessary changes.

Comment: I don't know what is really wrong with your code. When I call the following code in the browser console `window.location.href = 'mailto:email@domain.com?subject=Sample subject&body=Sample content'` it works perfectly fine

Comment: I just realized that you're not looking to set a body in general, but to add specific mark-up. As far as I know, it's not possible to set HTML content. Your options are limited to just a few parameters, and the length of the text you can add is pretty limited as well, although the specific browser and mail client used could be more forgiving. The two linked questions provide pretty much all there is to know about mailto links.

Comment: @GolezTrol thats what I wanted to confirm that its not possible. Thanks for the comment. Do you know any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: I've added another reference question that mentions the RFC that states that the body is designed to be small because it was not intended at all for full fledged mails. I also found [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body/46699855#46699855) is an interesting alternative...

Comment: But personally, I think this whole set-up is too fragile to begin with. I think it's better to have a web-form and a server side script that mails or saves the data. That way, you don't rely on the user's client at all. After all, they may not even have one installed or configured properly (webmail?), which means the whole thing is unusable to them. I just found out that I'm an example of such a user. I use gmail in the browser, but mailto links are handled by the Windows Mail client, which was not set up at all.

Comment: Yes you are correct :) all the aspects you mentioned force me to think towards server side scripting. I'll go for it. Thanks