# Javascript - save clickable link in string

Tags: javascript

So I have function like this which is called on `button` click:

```
function sendEmail() {
    var subject = 'test subject';
    var href = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
    var body = 'test body: ' + href;

    window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + body;
}
```

Is it possible to save this `href` in email body as a real link not as a `string` ??

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It's not possible. See similar question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mailto link with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body)

Comment: Instead of using window.location.href you can either use submit form or Ajax call so you can transfer any data of any type.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible to implement like this because body should be plain text here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your mail function to send Content-Headers for TEXT/HTML instead of TEXT/PLAIN.

If so you can use simple html to send the mail.
That would make the link look like:

```
function sendEmail() {
    var subject = 'test subject';
    var href = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
    var body = 'test body: <a href="' + href + '">Any Description</a>';
}
```

If your solution would work it would be possible to force people to redirect to another page by reading their mails and for sure this should not be the case.