# How to write html content with mailto?

Tags: angularjs, mailto

I want to create a html table in the body of a mail with angular Js and mailto.

This is my code :

Html

```
 <button type="button ng-click=outlook()>email</button>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.outlook=function(){
    var emailId ="abc@gmail.com"
    var ccEmail ="xyz@gmail.com"
    var subject ="testing"
    var body= "<table><tr><td>Nbr</td><td>Name</td></tr></table>"

    window.location.href = "mailto:" + emailId + "?cc=" + ccEmail + "&subject=" + 
subject + "&body=" + body;
};
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mailto link with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body)

Comment: You have typos on your button missing double quotes on closing type and for ng-click