# HTML content not working in window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open system's default mail client, with some content through JS like this: 
`` window.location.href = `mailto:user@example.com?subject=${subject}&body=${message}`; ``. The message contains some hyper link like `<a href="google.com">Google</a>`. In chrome browser, the hyperlink is appearing as expected. But when I try to open from Firefox, the mail client body shows it as a plain text. That is `<a href="google.com">Google</a>` itself. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: So there is no way to add HTML content to mail through JavaScript?

Comment: Not by using the `mailto`. Although you can look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699855/479156) on that same question.