# Flutter 1.22.6 - url_launcher - Sending HTML email

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I have two problems with the url_launcher: ^5.7.10
First Problem:
When I try to send an email with html tag, on a real device, if I use Gmail application the body of my email is not well formated. I see the HTML tags. I tried with or without HTML5 doctype
Second Problem:
When I try to send an email with an Href tag the email body is cut at the equal sign.

My code is

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'URL Launcher',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'URL Launcher'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<void> _sendMailHtml(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
        url
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _launched = _sendMailHtml('mailto:smith@example.org?subject=News&body=<h1>Header 1</h1><p>Paragraph</p>');
                }),
                child: const Text('Send Mail HTML'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _launched = _sendMailHtml('mailto:smith@example.org?subject=News&body=<h1>Header 1</h1><p>Paragraph</p><a href="https://google.com">Link</a><p>End of mail</p>');
                }),
                child: const Text('Send Mail HTML With HREF'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My pubspec.yaml is

```
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

I did not try with flutter 2 because my app is in production and I have some dependencies errors.

For the first problem if I try with another email app, I can see the good formatting.

On Android 10...

screenshots :

[first problem on Gmail app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPWUx.png)

[on other email app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUuqN.png)

[Second problem with Gmail and anchor tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSNai.png)

Answer (score 0):

The mailto `body` parameter only supports plaintext messages. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body).

If you want you can check out the [mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer) package which has an interface for sending HTML emails, as shown in the linked page.

Comment: But Mailer send the email with a SMTP Server, I want open the email app of the phone.
Edit And if you look one of my screenshot you will see that it worked on an email app.