# How to create an HTML Email using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create an HTML email using JavaScript so that the draft is ready, and the user can send the email.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
location.href = "mailto:"+"isflibrary.net.com.de.xxx"+'?cc='+"emailCC"+'&subject='+("Stuff bought by: ", email)+'&body='+"<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com">Visit mywebsite.com!</a>";
```

Wrong output:
[image: wrong output]

Output that I want:
[image]

Comment: In case the OP provides the example as executable snippet one (the OP too) immediately could see whether and/or where the approach does fail.

Comment: even if `email` was declared `... + ("Stuff bought by: " , email ) + ...` obviously features a wrong syntax. Within the concatenation there can not be all of a sudden two comma separated values

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were trying to do?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    mailto = 'isflibrary.net.com.de.xxx';
    emailCC = 'test@emailCC.com';
    subject = 'Stuff bought by: ' + mailto;
    htmlBody = '<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com">Visit mywebsite.com!</a>';
    location.href = "mailto:" + mailto + "?cc=" + emailCC + "&subject=" + subject + "&body=" + htmlBody;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=btn>e-mail</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the body still appears as HTML code.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was a syntax problem, so I have bad news. It can't be done:  [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body)