# How to prefill formatted html when opening email client?

Tags: javascript, html-email, apple-mail

First I create the formatted html:

```js
onClick={(_) => {
        const content = `Nézd mit találtam ..<div></div`;
```

then assign `content`

```
window.location.href = `mailto:user@example.com?subject=Jelentkezz vagy oszd meg és nyerj 250$-t&body=${content}`
```

but in Apple Mail it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mailto link with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body)

Comment: basically it is not possible, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520399/11262020).

As mentioned in the answers to this question, it's **not** possible to format the body using HTML in `mailto`.

But there are a few other possibilities to achieve the same result. I won't repeat them here, as they are already explained in detail in the other question.