# open email with url link in typescript

Tags: html, typescript

I have the following code:

```
       generateDownloadLink(document: Document) {
            const url = environment.apiBase + 'apps/reports/dashboard-management/documentId:' + document.myBitDocId;
            return `
            <a href="${url}" style="text-decoration: underline; color: blue;">click here (${document.categoryName})</a>`;
            }
        
    
     getMailData(){
        if(this.customer && this.customer.email){
         this.mailRecipient = this.customer.email;
        this.mailSubject = this.customer.firstName +" " + this.customer.lastName + " " + this.customer.idNUmber;
        const selected = this.documents.filter(x=>x.selected == true) as Document[];
        
        const downloadLinks = selected.map(document => this.generateDownloadLink(document));
        if(selected)
        this.mailBody = `לצפייה במסמכים: <br>${downloadLinks.join('<br>')}`;
        const mailtoLink = `mailto:${this.mailRecipient}?subject=${encodeURIComponent(this.mailSubject)}&body=לצפייה במסמכים: ${downloadLinks}`;
        const mailLink = document.getElementById("mailLink") as HTMLAnchorElement;
        window.location.href = mailtoLink;

        // mailLink.href = mailtoLink;
        // mailLink.click();

      }
      else
      this.showNoEmailPopup = true;
    }
```

the problem is the html is coming as text and not as html, this is why I can't get url as link that can be pressed on "click me" how to fix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mailto link with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body)