# How to share html content with mail button in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, email, outlook

We are creating an Angular app, and we use `share-buttons` component to allow user to share his referral code.
The problem is that, I can't use `email` button to send html content in the mail body. It is always displayed as a plain text.

```
<share-buttons theme="modern-dark"
           [include]="['copy', 'facebook', 'email',  'linkedin','twitter',  'whatsapp']"
           [showIcon]="true"
           [showText]="false"
           [url]="referral"
           [title]="subject"
           [description]="descMsg">
</share-buttons>
```

[image]

I need to be able to configure the email style, as it may contains messages in Arabic letters, so the text direction will be changed to "RTL". And also, I need to embed the referral link into an anchor or a button.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to combine `mailto` and html mail body together.

[This was widely discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body/13415988#13415988).

As for the Arabic text, the mailing application of the user's device should handle text alignment by itself as long as it's not mixed with other characters.