# Rails 2 How to Render a view as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, pdfkit

I am using PDFKit to generate a pdf from a view but I can't seem to find an easy way to store the output from a url as a text string.

I tried this:

```
html = render_to_string(:template => "/portal/quotes/order/" + quote_id, :layout => false)
```

with quote_id being `216` in this case but I get this error:

```
Missing template /portal/quotes/order/216.erb in view path app/views
```

All my views are `.rhtml` format, not sure where it's getting the `.erb` extension from.

The url works as expected when navigated to in the browser.

Comment: sorry maybe i'm misunderstanding - are you looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353742/url-encode-equivalent-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: thanks, not quite what I'm looking for, basically I just want the output of a webpage which happens to be a view in my app

Comment: "erb" is the default format used if you don't define which one you want, try to use `"/portal/quotes/order/#{quote_id}.html.rhtml"` (I don't know the exact extension of your views, use the appropriate one)

Comment: @MrYoshiji - thanks, will try that but don't think it will work as a url of that format will just cause an error, the url is `http://localhost/portal/quotes/order/216` (no file extension) as the view file itself is `order.rhtml`

Comment: There is a big difference between a rendered action after a ActionDispatch::Request has been received (with params, headers, content-type, etc) than just a `render_to_string`. Try it and we'll see if it works ;)

Comment: @MrYoshiji thanks, just tried it, no joy, also tried `html = render_to_string(:template => "/portal/quotes/order/#{quote_id}.rhtml", :layout => false)` since all my views are just `rhtml` and not `.html.rhtml`. Same error - `missing template`

Comment: OH, i'm so blind ... Of course it does not exists, we are trying to find view containing the id of the quote! The file is show.rhtml, not <id>.rhtml ! Try this: `render_to_string(:template => "/portal/quotes/order/show.rhtml", :layout => false, locals: { id: quote_id })`

Comment: @MrYoshiji thanks, had to change the syntax slightly, `html = render_to_string(:template => "/quotes/order.rhtml", :layout => false, :locals => { :id => quote_id })` This is the physical path of the view within my app but I use the `portal` part to decide which layout to use. This just leads to an error though as it can't find the dynamic information within the view so I assume this request doesn't go through the controller? Not sure if what I want is possible, would it be better to grab the page contents using something like `RestClient`?

Comment: @MrYoshiji just read another answer and read that using `locals` gives you an instance variable so managed to get it work, thank you. Only issue I have now is that when using `number_to_currency` the `£` is not encoded properly

Comment: Okay great so it works! Just a matter of encoding with this sign

Comment: yip, thanks for your help, do you know if it's possible to do `<%= number_to_currency(total_rental_price, :unit => "&pound;")` instead of `<%= number_to_currency(total_rental_price, :unit => "£")`, not sure where the issue is, all pages should be utf-8. __EDIT__ should have tried it before asking, it does indeed seem to work :) Thank you again, doing it this way instead of a hardcoded string also seems to have fixed an issue I had with pdfkit and pagebreaks

Comment: When you create your PDF, make sure you use the proper encoding to display this sign (UTF-8 can display the pound sign? I don't know).

Comment: yeah, it's utf-8 compatible, must be an option I need to set with pdfkit in `environment.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
html = render_to_string(:template => "/quotes/order.rhtml", :layout => false, :locals => { :id => quote_id })
```

The `template` value is the physical path of the template in the `views` directory and not the url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a template path on the template param, not a relative url. The template path you want to use should be something like `'orders/show'` or something like that. And this must be located at the views folder.