# url encoding for every request and response in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-3.2, urlencode

i did some google to know about url encoding but, i didn't found any exact solution for my problem so i am posting it here. 
I need to **encode each and every request** for my entire rails applications. the reason for this is i am ***passing some id in the url*** which needs to be encrypted for the user.
i couldn't get **any Gems or common library** for that. please guide me with your solution or direct me to the right path.

resource that i feel similar through:
[url encode equivalent in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353742/url-encode-equivalent-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I've done something similar, I created a method in my model: `def generate_link_token
    self.link_token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
  end` and store this in the database table automatically using a callback in the model : `before_create :generate_link_token` and when a link is retrieved, look up the record with the matching link token using a route that matches my desired structure. Your question is quite vague so not sure if doing it this way matches your particular requirements.

Comment: Why not just calculate the id on-the-fly? Why store it in the database?

Comment: What about storing the ID in a session?

Comment: Any reason for encryption? Can you not validate that the current user has permission to access that ID when the linked URL loads? (I'm assuming here it is to stop other users from guessing URLs).