# Ruby/Rails - escape uri for use in css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application, a user uploads an image, which I then put on S3. That image is then later used as a background for a div, using the following style

```
div#id { background: url('<%= creative.url %>') no-repeat;}
```

The creative url look something like:

`http://myhost.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/27/display/608-(rec'd_021014)_user_image.jpg?1392767029`

As above, the problem is that creative.url can contain special characters (quotes, parens, etc.), and according to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri, it needs to be escaped.

I'm hoping there's some convenient ruby/rails function that can take care of this for me.

If not, then I'd probably need to do some kind of regex replace - what would that look like?

**Update:**

Folks have suggested using URI encoding functions - I did try that, but the url string is used directly in the ERB template, so it would encode the whole thing which wouldn't work in the css url function  - i.e., I would something like (from above):

`div#id {background: url('http%3A%2F%2Fmyhost.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com%2F27%2Fdisplay%2F608-(rec%27d_021014)_user_image.jpg%3F1392767029') no-repeat;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`URI(url)`
or 
`URI.encode(url)`
or
`URI.decode(url)`
or 
`URI.parse(url)`

Depends of the case

You may need to load `require 'uri'` before

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way is to use url_encode from [ERB::Util](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB/Util.html#method-c-url_encode)

In Rails, there is an [alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353742/url-encode-equivalent-in-ruby-on-rails) `u` for url_encode.

```
div#id { background: url('<%=u creative.url %>') no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Rails has any CSS escaping helper, but [the JS escaping helper `j`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j) would be better than nothing as it would escape quotes, closing brackets, and backslashes. There may be some special CSS characters that would not be touched, though.

You could set a `data-` attribute on the element in question, then use [the CSS `attr` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) to reference it. This way you can use it in CSS without having to worry about it escaping it for CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a file named `jeux'); background-image: url('nope.jpg`.

and the only thing that worked was:

```rb
  def escape_css(string)
    string.gsub("'", "\\\\'")
  end
```

(I tried `CGI.escape`, `URI.escape`, `u`, and `String#dump`)

full code:

```
  .h-32.bg-cover.bg-no-repeat.bg-center(style="background-image: url('#{escape_css category_image_url(category)}')")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use dump.

```
div#id { background: url('<%= creative.url.dump %>') no-repeat;}
```

Comment: looks unrelated https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-dump